# Code runs inside IDE but fails outside

Tags: java, linux, maven, terminal, lanterna

I am trying to run an example code with Java Lanterna for a terminal GUI. Running the example within Netbeans 8.2 IDE successfully runs (essentially klicking the 'Play' button), but running the JAR file from the Linux terminal fails.

Main.java:

```
package com.glasses.lanternatest;

import com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.screen.Screen;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal.Terminal;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Screen screen = TerminalFacade.createScreen();
        screen.startScreen();
        screen.putString(10, 5, "Hello World!", Terminal.Color.WHITE, Terminal.Color.BLACK);
        screen.refresh();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        screen.stopScreen();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.glasses</groupId>
    <artifactId>LanternaTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.glasses.lanternatest.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.lanterna</groupId>
            <artifactId>lanterna</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The error I get when running the resulting JAR file from the terminal:

```
myuser@mylaptop:~$ java -jar /home/myuser/NetBeansProjects/LanternaTest/target/LanternaTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/lanterna/TerminalFacade
    at com.glasses.lanternatest.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 1 more
```

Why does running the code through the Linux terminal fail? Why doesn't it find the class `com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade` when run from the terminal, but successfully finds it when run the same code from within Netbeans 8.2 pressing the 'Play' button?

Comment: did u run mvn clean install first?

Comment: According to your POM setup you need to have all your jar dependencies in a folder “lib” beside your JAR.

Comment: @Strelok True, corrected that. Thank you.

Comment: You need to configure maven to include your dependencies, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028921/in-maven-my-dependencies-are-set-up-but-i-get-a-classnotfoundexception-when-i-r/24030042#24030042) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899985/this-project-cannot-be-added-because-it-does-not-produce-a-jar-file-using-an-ant/24900260#24900260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NetBeans project execution classpath is simply different than your command line execution classpath.

Instead of using `maven-jar-plugin` to put classpath entries into `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` it might be easier to use `maven-shade-plugin` to build a self-contained uber jar. Because this uber jar will include all the dependencies of your Maven module it won't have external classpath requirements, as per [shade mojo docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This solved it. I added the `maven-shade-plugin` and also added the Main-class file to the manifest file using `<transformer ...><mainClass>...</mainClass></transformer>`. Works fine now as fat JAR.

Answer (score 1):

You need what is called a Fat Jar. Basically, you are compiling your code, but not the library you are using. A Fat Jar compiles the libraries with your code.

**Disclaimer**: It is better style and coding practice to have your code load the library instead of packaging it with your code, however making a Fat Jar is easier.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included **how** to build your fat jar. As it is, this is only half of an answer.

Comment: I don't use maven, I don't know the particular plugin to use. That is a simple google search that @Socrates can make. I simply diagnosed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
I had the same problem...Thanks much for the suggestion....

Here is an excerpt my pom.xml from NetBeans
Make sure you allow NB to create a package for you ...

```
<build>
<plugins>`enter code here`
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation=
                "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>
                hanleysoft.brian_park_polymorphic_rpg_lanterna_2.RPG_Main
              </mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```